# What Exactly Does "Alignment.BASELINE" mean in a Java GroupLayout?

Tags: java, user-interface, grouplayout

I'm learning about `GroupLayout` in Java.

`Alignment.LEADING`, `CENTER`, and `TRAILING` makes sense to me,

but I have no idea what `BASELINE` means.

Where do the components get positioned if I indicate `Alignment.BASELINE`?

I know that this is a very basic question, but can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Alignment.BASELINE` works for components which renders a textual information (e.g. JLabel, JButton, etc). With `Alignment.BASELINE` alignment, the `GroupLayout` will align such components so that *the baseline of their text* stays on the same (horizontal) line (makes for an easier reading, the eye doesn't need to jump up/down on the virtual line of text).

See [Java Swing tutorial - GroupLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/groupExample.html) - specifically the 'Vertical Layout' section.

Comment: So simply, it positions the components along the "bottom", right?
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: "So simply, it positions the components along the "bottom", right?" Not quite, more like "along the baseline of their text" (so closer to vertically centred than bottom alignment). But, if your interpretation makes you happier, who am I to object?